# How to make moving buttons clickable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, kotlin

I wrote a rotation animation for a view which has 2 buttons in it, anim xml:

```
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:interpolator="@anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:duration="10000"
    android:repeatMode="restart"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="0"
    />
```

The issue with this is that the location of the buttons seem to be fixed on the screen in the place where I put it in the XML, so when the buttons move clicking on them does nothing. I tried implementing rotation animation using RotateAnimation class but it was identical, buttons can only be clicked in the place where they were put in the XML, how to make the buttons actually movable?